# what's the 'right' way to do a MVC for JSPs in Java EE 5?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets

I've inherited an incomplete but small web project (Java EE 5, running on WebSphere 7).

The project consists mostly of JSPs that are accessed directly via their URL, and most JSPs look up their own reference to the EJBs (services) they need.  Also, there's a Servlet for every form that gets submitted by the HTML code in the JSPs.

Architecturally speaking, is there anything *wrong* with this?

I was thinking it would be better to have an MVC design.  I don't want to convert everything to JSF because I don't want to convert all the HTML and embedded Java scriptlets into JSF tags and managed beans.

I don't really want to use Struts or Spring MVC because they're not part of the Java EE 5 toolkit that comes out of the box with WebSphere, and I don't want to add additional complexity with the additional libs and config files.

I was thinking about building my own little MVC with a "ControllerServlet" that accepts a command and dynamically build and execute the command object, and redirect to the JSP view.

But I ask myself again, is there anything "wrong" with JSPs that post to Servlets?  It's actually kind of elegant in its simplicity.

What do you think?

Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated!  Rob

Comment: A drop-dead simple front controller is [Bear's FrontMan](http://www.bibeault.org/frontman/). Being worried about adding non-EE libraries is probably counter-productive; an app of any complexity will already have a bunch of dependencies, and massaging it into a framework may be worth the effort. I'm not a fan of multiple-app-entry-patterns (e.g., some URLs are JSP, some are servlets), I'd rather things were consistent--there's no technical reason it *has* to be consistent, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking a rather subjective/localized question. But ala.

There's technically nothing wrong with individual JSPs that submit to individual servlets. The only real problem is when the servlets turn out to contain duplicated code for quite common tasks like collecting request parameters, converting/validating them, setting bean properties, invoking actions, performing navigation. *That* is not DRY and is what a MVC framework with a single front controller and a well definied lifecycle is supposed to solve.

Or, if the servlet's tasks are actually well refactored with homegrown code to perform those common tasks, then this is in turn not very maintainable as no one else than the original developer knows the ins and outs of this custom framework. So it's hard to find anyone else willing to maintain this webapp without learning *another* framework again which the new developer wouldn't likely to see in other future webapps. *That* is why companies usually adopt an existing and well-developed MVC framework like JSF, Spring MVC, Stripes, Struts, etc.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, great answer. Does Java EE include another lighter JSP-oriented MVC technology, other than JSF?

Comment: No, JSF is the only as offered by Java EE. Component based MVC frameworks tend to be more "heavyweight", but you end up with much simpler code. If you're looking for a "lightweight" request based MVC framework, you may find Spring MVC or Stripes interesting. Regardless of the choice for the new framework, this requires quite some refactoring on an existing webapp. "If it ain't broken, don't fix it".

Comment: Thanks, your sober second opinion on this is very useful.